# How do you add a request header with OkHttpClient + RetroFit?

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I would like to add this request header [via Java-code]:
**X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest**

Comment: It's described in the Retrofit overview at http://square.github.io/retrofit/ - first result that Google yields on "retrofit" search.

Comment: I was hoping to find a java solution as to not be redundant in w/ adding all these annotations.

Comment: Using an OkHttp `Interceptor` would be the easiest way to add the header to all of the requests that the `OkHttpClient` makes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can probably do something like this

```
public interface UserService {  
@Headers("X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest")
@GET("/tasks")
List<Task> getTasks();
```

}